# Keychain error -25308 while trying to add drive to Time Machine

Tags: time-machine, macos, keychain

I am trying to configure my Mac to use a time-capsule for Time Machine. After entering in the Time Capsule password I get the following error:

> Keychain error -25308 occurred while creating a System Keychain entry
>   for the username "Bob" and URL
>   "afp://Bob@TimeCapsule._afpovertcp._tcp.local/TM"
>
> You can try using the Keychain Access utility to edit or repair your
>   System Keychain

I've tried repairing my keychain, using the Keychain Access utility:

```
Repair started
Checking keychain configuration for Bob (user ID=501)
Home directory is /Users/Bob
Checked login keychain
Checked password for ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
Checked settings for ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
Checked default keychain
Checked contents of ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
No problems found
Repair completed
```

I even got desperate enough to wipe the drive and reinstall Mavericks, and it still occurs. I get the same error if I try and set it up to use a NAS instead of the time-capsule.

The time-capsule works for another Mac in my house. I've tried wiping the keychain and starting from scratch. Nothing works.

Does anyone know what I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

I was having this same problem. According to discussion at [this thread](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=1225417) on Ars Technica, it’s caused by a bug in iStat Server. Are you running this?

I was, and can confirm that the work-around solution posted there of removing [iStat Server](http://bjango.com/mac/istatserver/) and deleting the iStat Server entry in `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.security.plist` has worked for me.  The relevant entry looks like this:

```
<key>DefaultKeychain</key>
<array>
   <dict>
      <key>DbName</key>
      <string>/Library/Application Support/iStat Server/iStatServer.keychain</string>
      <key>GUID</key>
      <string>{87191ca3-0fc9-11d4-849a-000502b52122}</string>
      <key>SubserviceType</key>
      <integer>6</integer>
   </dict>
</array>
```

Bjango, the developer of iStat Server, has further posted on the Ars Technica thread that a new version of iStat Server is now available.  I have not independently verified that this addresses the problem, since the above work-around had already taken care of my issue, but their release notes say simply “Fixed a Keychain issue.”  Both the new version and the release notes can easily be found at the iStat Server link above.